# What exactly does charge density mean in Gauss's law?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

I am familiar with Gauss's law, how it can be derived and, and how it can be applied (when in integral form)

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \rho$$

But I do not feel I really understand what is meant by $\rho$, to me the definition of charge density only makes sense when you are given a volume, and charges contained within. But neither of those things have been defined here.

So my question is what does $\rho$ really represent here? Is it just assumed that all of space is taken up by uniformly distributed charges that produce an electric field?

Comment: Take any point in space. Consider a small volume $d\tau$ around it, which has say a charge $dq$. Then the _definition_ of the charge density is $\rho=dq/d\tau$. This can be done at all points, so the number $\rho$ above represents a scalar function. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. In mechanics there is a distinction between average speed and instantaneous speed. Does such a distinction exist for charge density?

Comment: Also notice that you can include point particles, which must have infinite charge density, by using $\rho(\mathbf{r})=q \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0})$ for a particle located at position $\mathbf{r_0}$, and $\delta$ is the dirac delta function. The position itself can also be a function of $t$.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of mass density, and understand that mass density can vary with position? (For example, the core of the Earth is denser than the mantle and the crust.) Well, charge density is the same idea, but for charge instead of mass.

Comment: I think I understand now, I was confused as I didn't realize $\rho$ represents a scalar function. Is there a reason charge density is denoted by $\rho$, as opposed to $\rho\left( \overrightarrow{r} \right)$ ?

Comment: @cookiecainsy As it turns out, the charge density is a scalar function defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that $\rho=\rho(\vec r)$. The charge density can also be a function of time, however, not in the electrostatic case.

Comment: Note that the field is written as $\mathbf E$, not $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$. So it should not surprising that the same terse notation is used for the charge density, with the position dependence being implicitly understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge density in Gauss' law is simply a scalar function that specifies the distribution of charge in a region of space. The region may be 1, 2, or 3-dimensional as the case demands. Essentially, $\rho$ specifies the nature of the source of the electrostatic field, in terms both of its magnitude and geometry. When you integrate it over all space you get the net charge contained in the region:
$$Q_{\text{net}}=\int_{\text{all space}}\rho(\vec r)\;dV.$$
Essentially, Gauss' law tells one that the nature of the electric field depends on the distribution of charge in space. It is important to realize that the charge density can be a set of discrete point charges, an oddly shaped continuous yet non-uniform space charge or any combination of the two. The charge can also be distributed over the surface of a conductor. It is important to remember that the integral must exist for well-posed problems, for example, a constant charge density for all points in space leads to infinite net charge and a consequently infinite electric field, thus it makes sense that physical charge densities should be mindful of the convergence of $\int\rho\; dV$. Any distribution of charge is fair (even infinite densities) if it is finite in its spatial extension, however, if the charge is to go to infinity in it's spatial extension, then one must take care to ensure that the net charge is still finite.

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine that all charge distributions are composed of infinitesimal charges. $\rho$ describes how these infinitesimal charges are distributed. It does not need to be uniform (in this case, one would have $\rho = \text{constant}$).

Notice that classical electrodynamics does not know that charge is quantized. You might be thinking that in practice we have a finite number of electrons in a given volume and we use the positions of these electrons in order to calculate $\rho$. This is not how it works in classical electrodynamics. While in practice we do have a finite number of charges distributed in someway, we model these charge distributions using the function $\rho$. This can be understood as an averaging procedure of the actual detailed distribution in terms of a finite number of electrons. This simplification makes it easier to perform calculations and yields good results.